# sys.stdin.read() returns empty string

Tags: python-3.x

I am on Python 3.5 inside Spyder 3.1.3. When I enter the following code, `x` has an empty string. I am not  asked for any user input. Cursor directly goes to the next line

```
import sys

x = sys.stdin.read()

print(x)
```

So after executing this code, `x = ''`  So what is happening here ?

Answer (score 2):

When the cursor jumps to the newline, it has started to read from `stdin`, so anything you type would be passed to variable `x` and then re-printed once you break out from `stdin`.

If you want user input you can use:

```
x = input('Say something: ')
```

Comment: actually, when I run the program in the command prompt in windows, it does print the the value of `x`, but inside the Spyder console, the cursor just goes to the next line without waiting for the input. and if I type `x` there , it will just print an empty string

Comment: so it seems that the Spyder console does not behave like a system terminal. How can I have Spyder console behave like system terminal in windows ?

Comment: Sorry I don't know Spyder

Answer (score 2):

The stdin and stdout are references to file descriptors for the host OS. You didn't state the system you were running on, however in Linux; any process that is a child of the initializing process would share the same stdin / stdout.

As an example, when running from the command line or terminal, you can pipe information into it.

```
echo "Say something: " | ./yourscript.py
```

yourscript.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
    print('boom', line)
```

Comment: so is Spyder console different from command prompt on windows ?